# Current folder window not accessible in Matlab

Tags: matlab, window, pdw-file-browser

[image]I installed Matlab and set the path. After that, only the command window, the command history and the workspace windows were visible. I couldn't find the current folder window anywhere (it did not even appear in the desktop tab). After typing in the command window "filebrowser" an error appears. Suddenly, I get the current folder window but it is not accessibe or there is an error as It doesn't show any of the files and folders on it. 
I attach a picture of the Matlab screenshot where you can see the error displayed in the command window and how the current folder window appears.

Any help? What is the problem? How can solve this problem?

Any help is much appreaciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Consider increasing heap space. The reason for the error is because Java doesn't have enough memory. The error message is however very generic and could be particular to your workflow, but with the command history in the picture, I do not see a problem. Do follow the technical support solution for increasing heap space - http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18I2C/